# How to solve Your in-app purchase has been returned

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, review, subscriptions

In my app I have a subscription.

I’ve submitted it to the app review team and it was approved. But after I received a message from the review team that my subscription is returned and that I should change the promotional image of my subscription. Message: “To resolve this issue, please revise your promotional image to ensure it is unique and accurately represents the associated promoted in-app purchase”

I changed the image, pressed save but nothing happens (I don’t see “in review” status or similar info showing that the team working on my edits) I still see the alert that subscription returned.

I've submitted the new version but still the same returned message.

And in app purchase still has approved status. The question is the following. How to fix this Returned issue?

Any solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two options:

1. You can reject your approved app, re-attach your IAP and resubmit together.
2. You can submit the IAP [separately](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html) and wait to put your app live until the IAP is approved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Trying out with the mix of the 1st and the 2nd option: recreated and resubmitted the InApp purchase and added a new app version with a new InApp Purchase ID. Deleted the old in App Purchase on iTunes and From binary. Now the new InApp purchase is in "Waiting for Review" on iTunes Connect.